# SiteMinder FCC header variables appear in IIS but not AJP-connected Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, iis, http-headers, single-sign-on, siteminder

I'm running IIS 7.5 and Tomcat 5.5, connected via an AJP connector.  I also have a SiteMinder web agent configured on the machine.

For some reason, the SiteMinder header variables such as SM_USER or SM_USERDN are not appearing in Tomcat.  I don't see them in the Tomcat logs or in the browser, via an HTTP Proxy like Fiddler.  Interestingly, they do show up on an ASP page by iterating through all the server variables.  If I log into SiteMinder in IIS, the SiteMinder variables are present. On Tomcat, they cannot be found.

Understand that on both IIS and Tomcat, I can log in successfully, with SiteMinder returning an SMSESSION cookie.  In IIS, I log in through the browser.  In Tomcat, I'm calling the login.fcc from inside a servlet and submitting it using a group of Apache classes like httpclient and HttpPost.  The response in Tomcat does not contain the SiteMinder variables, though.

I don't understand why I can authenticate successfully, yet it's not responding with the SiteMinder variables.

What could be the issue or issues here?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You won't see the variables using an HTTP proxy like Fiddler because they are passed between the WebAgent and IIS in this case, and never make it to the browser.  You need to check that IIS is forwarding the headers properly to Tomcat.